# How to make android manifest file size smaller?

Tags: android, xml, gradle, manifest

[image]

AndroidManifest taking 534 bytes I want to shrink this file. is there any possible ways to convert this file even smaller I have seen some apps like

[Smallest App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nabin.lrrh)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=b.a&hl=en

how this is possible??

Comment: This app doesn't have any permissions, and very few activities. It's helpful for smaller AndroidManifest.

Comment: 534 bytes is tiny - probably a lot less than the operating system per-file overhead; so making it smaller isn't going to solve any problems.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm going to develop world smallest application that's why